# Can not update in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.04, updates

when want to update in Ubuntu 13.10 I get this error:

[image]

How I update now?

Comment: Can you please paste the output of: sudo apt-get update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you recently added a PPA or somehow lost the keys to the Ubuntu official repositories you just have to run:

sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com **keynumber**

The **keynumber** for the default repositories is **437D05B5**

Comment: yeah finally I solved my problem,
first I checked the output of this command:"sudo apt-get update"
I saw some errors in output about my printer driver..I deleted it in "Update Sources" next I saw one error about one key..I used your command and replace that key had error..I ran "sudo apt-get update" again and no problem now! Thank you